# No me acepta la consulta parametrizada

Tags: php

buenos días. Tengo el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param()

Estoy probando a utilizar una sentencia preparada para un SELECT, pero no me lo aceptan en cambio si lo hago lo hago utilizando variables, si me lo acepta y me sale el resultado esperado.

El dato que que quiero parametrizar es un integer.

La sentencia es correcta, ya que si no fuera correcta no me saldria bien ni poniendo la variable en vez del  ?

```
public function mostrarPerfil($nia){

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nia = ?";

            $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

            $result->bind_param('i',$nia);
            $result->execute();
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                    $usuario = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    return $usuario;
                }

                $result->close();
                $this->conn->close();
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da la sensación de que mezclas métodos de consultas preparadas y no preparadas. Te doy las dos opciones:

**No preparada**

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nia = ".$nia;
    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $usuario = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        print_r($usuario);
    }
    $this->conn->close();
```

**Preparada**

```
    $sql = "SELECT nombre FROM usuario WHERE nia = ?";
    $result = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $result->bind_param('i',$nia);
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($nombre);
    $result->fetch();
    echo $nombre;
    $result->close();
    $this->conn->close();
```

Fíjate que el `query()` 'equivale' al `prepare()`, `bind_param()` y `execute()`, necesitas declarar en qué variable vas a guardar el resultado con `bind_result()` y, en cada `fetch()`, vas actualizando el valor de la variable `$nombre`.

Es más laborioso, pero más seguro.

En php.net tienes los detalles:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli.php

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

**Preparada con más campos**

```
    $sql = "SELECT nombre,apellido FROM usuario WHERE nia = ?";
    $result = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $result->bind_param('i',$nia);
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($r[0],$r[1]);
    $result->fetch();
    echo $r[0].' '.$r[1];
    $result->close();
    $this->conn->close();
    return $r;
```

Comment: Entiendo el ejemplo, pero cómo haría para poder utilizar  todos los datos? he probado poniéndolo en bind_result mas variables y me imprime   los datos con el echo, pero y si quisiera   utilizar esas variables por separado?  Espero que se me entienda

Comment: Amplío la respuesta para que lo veas...